# How do we prove these $\sigma$-algebras are not independent?

Tags: probability, independence, extreme-value

Given the sequence $(X_n), n=1,2,... $, of iid exponential random variables with parameter $1$, define:

$$ M_n := \max \left\{ X_1, \frac{X_1+X_2}{2}, ...,\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{n} \right\} $$
I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}(M_n)$.

Define for $k = 1, 2, ..., n$

$$Y_k := \frac{X_1 + ... + X_k}{k}$$

Then we have $E[Y_k] = 1$

We can rewrite:

$$M_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k 1_{A_{n,k}}$$

where $A_{n,k}$ is the event that $Y_k = \max\{Y_1, ..., Y_n\}$

I was thinking that $E[M_n] = 1$ using independence, but then again, intuitively, the larger $Y_k$ is, the greater is the probability that it is the maximum.

Why rigorously is it that $\sigma(Y_k)$ and $\sigma(A_{n,k})$ are not independent?

I know that $\sigma(Y_k) = \{Y_k^{-1}(B) | B \in \mathscr B\}$ but have no clue as to what Borel set to use.

Comment: Why would it be true that $E(M_n) = 1$?  Clearly $M_n \geq Y_n$ and the inequality is strict with positive probability so $E(M_n) > E(Y_n) = 1$.

Comment: The terminology may be misleading you. The definition of independence of sigma algebras is actually about the *probability measures* defined on them. Therefore, you can prove lack of independence by choosing suitable events and doing a probability calculation.

Comment: @dsaxton =1 if we have independence but we don't. I was thinking that $M_n$ is going to be one of the $Y_k$'s and each of the $Y_k$'s has expectation 1, but I guess some $Y_k$'s will have greater probability than others...?

Comment: @whuber What do you mean? Choosing a Borel set is choosing an element of $\sigma(Y_k) \subseteq \mathscr F$ right?

Comment: @BCLC All the $Y_k$ have mean one, whether or not they're independent (they aren't) doesn't change this.  I think pursuing the question of independence here won't help you calculate $E(M_n)$.

Comment: Fleshing out @whuber's comment: the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent iff all pairs of events $F \in \mathcal{F}$ and $G \in \mathcal{G}$ are independent.  Thus you may prove the $\sigma$-algebras in question are *not* independent by finding an event $F$ that depends only $Y_k$ but $\mathbb{P}(F,A_{n,k}) \neq \mathbb{P}(F)\mathbb{P}(A_{n,k})$.  dsaxton essentially gave you an example :)

Comment: @P.Windridge I know. [Choosing an event is equivalent to choosing a Borel set right?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511226/show-the-equivalence-of-these-definitions-of-independence-of-random-variables)

Comment: @dsaxton I know the $Y_k$'s aren't independent. I am not interested in calculating $E[M_n]$. I want to know why $Y_k$ and $A_{n,k}$ are not independent

Comment: Btw, I commend your effort on (apparently) working through a probability text book :)

Comment: @P.Windridge Um, thanks, but I got the original problem from Math SE

Comment: @BCLC Mathematical rigor aside (I don't see why it's needed here), it should be fairly intuitive why these are not independent.  If you're told that $Y_1 < \epsilon$ is $P(A_{n, 1})$ left unchanged?  What if $\epsilon$ is made small and $n$ large?

Comment: ok then I retract the comment :)

Comment: @dsaxton 'intuitively, the larger $Y_k$ is, the greater is the probability that it is the maximum.' ?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, pretty much.  Also consider the law of large numbers.  If ever $Y_k > 1$ then you can be certain that it will be exceeded only a finite number of times.  This definitely tells you something about the chance $Y_n$ is the max for different values of $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the easiest non-trivial case of $n=2$, $k=1$.

Thus, $Y_k = Y_1 = X_1$ and $Y_2 = (X_1 + X_2)/2$.

Observe that $A_{n,k} = A_{2,1} = \{Y_1 \geq Y_2\} = \{X_1 \geq X_2\}$, so we have $\mathbb{P}(A_{n,k}) = 1/2$ ([since the $X_i$'s are iid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539690/)).

Now examine the event that $Y_1 < t$ (any fixed $t > 0$). This has probability $\mathbb{P}(Y_1 < t) = 1-e^{-t}$.

On the other hand,
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y_1 < t, A_{2,1}) = \mathbb{P}(Y_1 < t, Y_1 \geq Y_2) = 
\mathbb{P}(X_2 \leq X_1 < t).
$$

The rhs can be calculated as
$$
\int_0^t \mathbb{P}(X_2 \leq u)e^{-u}du = \int_0^t (1 - e^{-u})e^{-u}du
$$
which is very much not equal to $\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-t})$!

[Edit: n.b. this answer concerns the independence, not how to calculate the expected maximum.]

Comment: Ah, if only I remembered $\sigma(Y_k) = \{Y_k \in (\infty, -a] | a \in \mathbb R\}$. Thanks P.Windridge ^-^

Comment: No probs :)  Rather than beginning from "find a Borel set such that [blah]" it's more helpful to try imagining what's going on intuitively, and trying to make it rigorous afterwards (if necessary) as @dsaxton suggests.  This is one of the basic idea in Polya's How to Prove it book.

Comment: (+1) BCLC: Since this question really concerns definitions, it seems worthwhile to nit-pick: $\sigma(Y_k)$ is much larger than just that collection of semi-infinite intervals!  It is only *generated* by them.  It includes much, much more complicated sets. This gives you far more flexibility than you otherwise might have thought in choosing an event to supply as a counterexample to the hypothesis of independence.

Comment: @whuber [What do you mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition)? Is the [equation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187440/how-do-we-prove-these-sigma-algebras-are-not-independent#comment356039_187451) wrong?

Comment: The formula in your comment is not entirely correct, as I have tried to explain. By definition, the countable union and finite intersection of elements of $\sigma(Y_k)$ must also be in $\sigma(Y_k)$, but that obviously is not the case for the collection you have written. Your expression has two problems. The first is that your intervals are all empty: you probably meant to write "$(-\infty, a]$." Second, that's still insufficient, because your collection doesn't contain (for instance) the interval $(0,1]=(-\infty,1] - (-\infty,0]$, which is in $\sigma(Y_k)$.

Comment: @whuber I see. Thanks. So should it be $\sigma(Y_k) = \sigma(\{Y_k \in (-\infty, a] | a \in \mathbb R \})$?

Comment: Yes, that conveys the right idea.  The main thing to remember is that it gives you great flexibility to select measurable subsets when assessing independence (or the lack thereof).

Comment: @whuber right thanks. Any idea if this is supposed to be taught in beginning probability theory classes? Not sure this was discussed or maybe I just forgot

Comment: @whuber Ah, I remember now: I think the one I gave above $\pi(x)$ and $\sigma(\pi(x)) = \sigma(x)$

Comment: @whuber back here after 5 years and when i 1st reread that comment i made about '$\sigma(Y_k) = \{Y_k \in (\infty, -a] | a \in \mathbb R\}$', i immediately thought like 'wait a minute...that can't be right...' yeah. good times. good times.